# How to convert PCM S16LE audio to MU-LAW/8000 using .NET (Windows/Mac/Linux)

Tags: c#, .net, audio, twilio, naudio

I'm trying to receive and transmit audio between a Twilio voice call and a Discord voice channel.
I'm struggling to figure out how to convert the audio data I'm receiving from [DSharpPlus](https://github.com/DSharpPlus/DSharpPlus) (Discord library for .NET) to the format required by Twilio Voice.

If I'm reading [DSharpPlus' docs correctly](https://dsharpplus.github.io/articles/audio/voicenext/transmit.html), the **PCM data coming from DSharpPlus is in PCM S16LE format**.
Twilio expects the data to be in MU-LAW/8000 format (excluding headers I believe).

I am trying to use [NAudio](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio) to convert the data, but all I'm hearing through the phone is sharp painful noises. I cannot use the full NAudio library as this project should work on Windows/Mac/Linux and some NAudio APIs are Windows only.
Here's the relevant code I currently have:

```cs
private async Task VoiceReceiveHandler(VoiceNextConnection connection, VoiceReceiveEventArgs args)
{
    
    if (twilioSocketConnectionManager.TryGetSocketById(socketId, out var twilioSocket) && twilioSocket.Socket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
    {
        var media = ConvertPcmToMulawBase64Encoded(args.AudioFormat, args.PcmData.ToArray());
        var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize<MediaMessage>
        (
            new MediaMessage("media", twilioSocket.StreamSid, new MediaPayload(media)), 
            jsonSerializerOptions
        );
        logger.LogInformation(json);
        var bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(json);
        var arraySegment = new ArraySegment<byte>(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        await twilioSocket.Socket.SendAsync(arraySegment, WebSocketMessageType.Text, WebSocketMessageFlags.EndOfMessage, CancellationToken.None);
    }
}

private static string ConvertPcmToMulawBase64Encoded(AudioFormat audioFormat, byte[] pcmData)
{
        
    var sourceFormat = new WaveFormat(audioFormat.SampleRate, 16, audioFormat.ChannelCount);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(EncodeMuLaw(pcmData, 0, pcmData.Length));
}

public static byte[] EncodeMuLaw(byte[] data, int offset, int length)
{
    var encoded = new byte[length / 2];
    int outIndex = 0;
    for(int n = 0; n < length; n+=2)
    {
        encoded[outIndex++] = MuLawEncoder.LinearToMuLawSample(BitConverter.ToInt16(data, offset + n));
    }
    return encoded;
}
```

I will also need convert from MU-LAW to PCM S16LE again, but first things first.
I'm completely oblivious when it comes to audio processing, so go easy on me.

Here's the rest of the source code: https://github.com/Swimburger/DiscordTwilioVoiceBot

Essentially my question is, **how do I convert PCM S16LE audio to MU-LAW/8000 using .NET while supporting Windows/Linux/Mac**?

---

Update 1:

Folks have suggested using ffmpeg instead of NAudio, which I think I'm correctly doing here, but I still hear sharp noise instead of the actual audio.

```cs
private async Task VoiceReceiveHandler(VoiceNextConnection connection, VoiceReceiveEventArgs args)
{
    var ffmpeg = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = "ffmpeg",
        Arguments = $@"-hide_banner -ac 2 -f s16le -ar 48000 -i pipe:0 -c:a pcm_mulaw -f mulaw -ar 8000 -ac 1 pipe:1",
        RedirectStandardInput = true,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true
    });

    //byte[] trimmedData = new byte[args.PcmData.Length - 44];
    //Buffer.BlockCopy(args.PcmData.ToArray(), 44, trimmedData, 0, trimmedData.Length);

    await ffmpeg.StandardInput.BaseStream.WriteAsync(args.PcmData);
    ffmpeg.StandardInput.Close();
    byte[] data;
    using(var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        ffmpeg.StandardOutput.BaseStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
        data = memoryStream.ToArray();
    }
    ffmpeg.Dispose();

    //byte[] trimmedData = new byte[data.Length - 44];
    //Buffer.BlockCopy(data, 44, trimmedData, 0, trimmedData.Length);

    //return;

    if (twilioSocketConnectionManager.TryGetSocketById(socketId, out var twilioSocket) && twilioSocket.Socket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
    {
        var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize<MediaMessage>
        (
            new MediaMessage("media", twilioSocket.StreamSid, new MediaPayload(Convert.ToBase64String(data))), 
            jsonSerializerOptions
        );
        logger.LogInformation(json);
        var bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(json);
        var arraySegment = new ArraySegment<byte>(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        await twilioSocket.Socket.SendAsync(arraySegment, WebSocketMessageType.Text, WebSocketMessageFlags.EndOfMessage, CancellationToken.None);
    }
}
```

This is on a [separate branch](https://github.com/Swimburger/DiscordTwilioVoiceBot/tree/ffmpeg).

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar question converting Twilio's MU-LAW to PCM 16LE to stream to Azure Cognitive Services transcription service. I was writing in Java rather than dotnet, and I did not find a good library solution.

However, the conversion can be done byte-at-a-time with a lookup table (note that one byte of mulaw is represented by 2 bytes of pcm). There is a [rather abstract description of the algorithm on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G.711#%CE%BC-law), and I found [this dotnet repo](https://github.com/chambersandpartners/twilio-transcription-poc/tree/master/TwilioMediaStreams/Services)'s code easily translatable to Java and it worked fine. For your case you will want to look in MulawDecoder.cs.

My resulting Java code for mulaw->pcm is [here](https://github.com/mjg123/twilio-media-streams-x-azure-cognitive-services-speech/blob/main/src/main/java/com/example/twilio/mediastreamsazuretranscription/azure/MulawToPcm.java).